# Qt printer custom paper size

Tags: c++, qt, printing, dialog

I have a Qt widget application where I want to print custom widgets (the size is different every time). My question is that how can I set custom paper size to the printer (in millimeter).
This is how I tried:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
printer.setPaperSize(QSize(myWidgetWidthMM, myWidgetHeightMM), QPrinter::Millimeter);

QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);

if (dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    myWidget->render(&painter);
}
```

But as soon as I open the QPrintDialog it sets back the paper size to A4. Later I noticed that QPrintDialog has some pre set paper sizes (A3, A4, A5, Statement, B4, B5, Executive, Legal, Letter, Tabloid) and if I set any different paper size (even pre defined, like A0), then it's back to A4.

Any ideas?

Comment: what platform are you using? On Windows and OS X, the native print dialog is used, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintdialog.html#details). which means there is nothing you can do there other than providing your own dialog instead of using `QPrintDialog`.

Comment: I use Windows. So I have to make my own dialog, get all the printers manually and then it will probably work as expected?

Comment: You can do it like this. you can display only the settings you want the user to be able to change (if that's what you are looking for).

Comment: I tried it without opening a printdialog, but it still sets back the paper size to A4...

Comment: How does it set back the paper size to A4? If you can write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can try asking a new question with this new problem.

Comment: QPrinter sets it back automatically if I set a custom size that is not in the built in size list. I figured out that custom size works only if the output isn't native but PDF. So I decided to stick with the built in sizes.

Comment: I can't tell what is the issue then (based on the current information), but maybe it is related to the printer you are using. Have you tried testing on other printers?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it on 3 different printers and the size list and the result is always the same. Now I use the provided sizes and everything works well.